# Tsc command will open up a popup within my VS terminal

Tags: typescript

I've installed everything correctly, and I double checked but for some reason, every times I want to use the tsc command to compile my .ts, it will just open up a popup. I have installed and re-installed everything, so I have no idea what could be the cause for this.

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because Windows doesn't know which is the default application for the `.ts` TypeScript file.

On Windows you can do **either of the following**:

1. Simply tick the checkbox saying "Always use this app to open `.ts` file" and choose `tsc` from the options shown to you in the popup.
2. You can also search for `Default Applications` and select `tsc` for `.ts` files.